# How to disable a selected list item when using Fx.Morph?

Tags: javascript, navigation, mootools

http://jsfiddle.net/chakri/92tqF/

I need help with the above code. I am trying to disable the hover effect for a selected item in the menu. But am unable to modify the Javascript (fairly new).

It is a vertical Navigation using Mootools Fx.Morph. I am trying to use a class "selectedleftnav" by applying it to the list item (the user will be on this page when he clicks the link). The menu will be unique for different pages, so I need to disable the selected item for each page.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you select the list elements to apply the effect using:

```
var list = $$('#idList LI');
```

You can improve the selector to exclude the selected one using the `:not()` selector pattern (that's the magic of [CSS3 selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors), supported by Mootools and available thanks to Mootools in every browser):

```
var list = $$('#idList LI:not(#selectedleftnav)');
```

**[Here you can see the resulting fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3JFt7/)**.